# VBA formula auto fill works independently but not with the rest of my code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying add an auto fill for a vlookup at the end of a larger code. The auto fill code that I wrote works as expected when it is in its own module: the formula begins in the second row of the column and fills until the last row. But when it's added to the end of the larger code, it seems to not interpret the range anymore. It puts the first formula in the first column where the header was and only fills the formula to the second row.

I found that when I altered the range, I either get a run-time error if I removed the row number or if I alter the number, it only increases or decreases the number of rows the formula fills.

I tried to just delete the larger code above and rerun just the auto fill and it continued to cause the issue. I also tried separating the subs and that didn't work either. It seems that only when it is in a new module completely separated from the the larger code will it work, and I can't understand why.

```
Sub FacilitiesReport()

ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Facilities Report"


Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\Users\12345\Desktop\FACILITIES.txt"

Open FilePath For Input As #1

row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, LineFromFile

    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(2)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(3)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 4).Value = LineItems(4)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 5).Value = LineItems(5)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 6).Value = LineItems(6)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 7).Value = LineItems(7)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 8).Value = LineItems(8)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 9).Value = LineItems(9)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 10).Value = LineItems(10)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 11).Value = LineItems(11)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 12).Value = LineItems(12)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 13).Value = LineItems(13)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 14).Value = LineItems(14)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 15).Value = LineItems(15)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 16).Value = LineItems(16)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 17).Value = LineItems(17)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 18).Value = LineItems(18)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 19).Value = LineItems(19)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 20).Value = LineItems(20)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 21).Value = LineItems(21)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 22).Value = LineItems(22)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 23).Value = LineItems(23)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 24).Value = LineItems(24)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 25).Value = LineItems(25)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 26).Value = LineItems(26)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 27).Value = LineItems(27)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 28).Value = LineItems(28)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 29).Value = LineItems(29)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 30).Value = LineItems(30)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 31).Value = LineItems(31)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 32).Value = LineItems(32)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 33).Value = LineItems(33)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 34).Value = LineItems(34)

    row_number = row_number + 1

Loop

Close #1

With Range("A1:AI1").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    Range("A1:AL1").Font.Bold = True


    Range("$AJ$1").Value = "TWC"
    Range("$AK$1").Value = "CCC"
    Range("$AL$1").Value = "TWH"

 Columns("AJ:AL").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Facilities Report\FacilitiesReport-1.csv"

Windows("FacilitiesReport-1.csv").Activate
Range("A1:K1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Facilities Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Facilities Report\FacilitiesReport-2.csv"

Windows("FacilitiesReport-2.csv").Activate
Range("A2:K2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Facilities Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Facilities Report\FacilitiesReport-3.csv"

Windows("FacilitiesReport-3.csv").Activate
Range("A2:K2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Facilities Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

'-----------VLOOKUP FROM SHEET 2---------------------------------

Windows("Facilities Report").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("AJ2:AJ" & Lastrow)
rng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-24],Sheet2!C[-35]:C[-25],10,)"

End Sub
```

This may be more code than is necessary, but I am not sure where the issue is stemming from. The auto fill is the last 11 lines.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: What is the value of Lastrow after `Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row` is executed?

Comment: also, you may need to specify `rng.Formula` as `rng.FormulaR1C1`...what are the contents of AJ2 after you run `rng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-24],Sheet2!C[-35]:C[-25],10,)`?

Comment: unrelated to your question...but I would eschew the use of copy/paste when moving ranges of values around. Copy/paste is unnecessary and slows the routine. Start setting ranges equal to each other instead. (e.g. `Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1:A10") = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1:A10").Value`

Comment: @MBB70 The value of Lastrow will always be different, as there report is a report of employees and fluctuates each time it is run. The contents of each cell in AJ are supposed to be a unique employee ID that corresponds to the identifier in the column L, which is true for AJ2 when it is run, but not the other cells. Plus it deletes the header for that column and puts the formula in AJ1.

Comment: That means the value of `Lastrow` is 1, i.e. column L is empty. Therein lies your problem. Are you referring to the right workbook/sheet?

Comment: @SJR that was it! I removed the thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1") and replaced it with ActiveSheet and it works perfectly now. Not sure why that completely flew over my head. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm well aware that lastRow is dynamic. I asked that question to help you figure out the problem. Might I recommend entering `print variableName` in the Immediate window to determine variable values as you're stepping through your code (or oftentimes you can just hover over them). Doing this would have revealed that Lastrow was incorrectly assigned from the outset.